# getting empty body in record action - twilio

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, twilio, plivo

**My use case:**

My case is that i'm making a bot for listening podcast in which user will make call to twilio number and bot will ask what type of podcast would you like to listen then record for 10 seconds

when recording finish, it say user to please wait while we are finding podcast

I want that recording in my webhook so i will figure out caller mood and find appropriate podcast mp3 file from my database and play to caller

**Issue I'm Facing:**

I'm getting empty body in all of my webhooks

**My code:**

```
var express = require("express");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var VoiceResponse = require('twilio').twiml.VoiceResponse;

var app = express();
var port = (process.env.PORT || 4000);

app.use(bodyParser.json())

// helper to append a new "Say" verb with alice voice
function say(text, twimlRef) {
    twimlRef.say({ voice: 'alice' }, text);
}
// respond with the current TwiML content
function respond(responseRef, twimlRef) {
    responseRef.type('text/xml');
    responseRef.send(twimlRef.toString());
}

app.post("/voice", function (request, response, next) {
    console.log("request: ", request.body); //body is comming as empty object

    var phone = request.body.From;
    var input = request.body.RecordingUrl;
    var twiml = new VoiceResponse();
    console.log("phone, input: ", phone, input);

    say('What type of podcast would you like to listen. Press any key to finish.', twiml);
    twiml.record({
        method: 'POST',
        action: '/voice/transcribe',
        transcribeCallback: '/voice/transcribe',
        maxLength: 10
    });

    respond(response, twiml);
});

app.post("/voice/transcribe", function (request, response, next) {
    console.log("request: ", request.body); //body is comming as empty object

    var phone = request.body.From;
    var input = request.body.RecordingUrl;
    var twiml = new VoiceResponse();

    var transcript = request.body.TranscriptionText;    
    console.log("transcribe text: ", transcript);

    //here i will do some magic(Ai) to detect user mood and find an 
    //appropriate mp3 file from my database and send to twilio

    var mp3Url = 'https://api.twilio.com/cowbell.mp3'

    say('start playing.', twiml);
    twiml.play(mp3Url);

    respond(response, twiml);
});

app.listen(port, function () {
    console.log('app is running on port', port);
});
```

**API Test with postman:**

[image]

[image]

**added url as webhook on twilio:**

[image]

**Heroku Logs:**

[image]

Comment: rather than request.body, you should try to display first request object. what it returns then you can get idea further.

also try to console.log response once.

Comment: I tried It, It's a very very large object but nothing in it

Comment: in postman I can see its https request, in your original code, have you checked about this protocol? either its http OR https? also do you have value set in input, phone (parameters you are using in form post)?

Comment: about https: heroku handle it, i used heroku many times nut never put my head in 's' part of https

Comment: according to this [document](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/record) it should give me these params in POST request body

Comment: just added one more screenshot in which i added url as webhook in twilio number

Comment: Shouldn't the call to your /voice URL be a GET instead of a POST? I think Twilio is doing a GET and your code is expecting a POST

Comment: twilio is doing POST request of course, you can see it in logs

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You are using `body-parser` which is good. However, you are using the JSON parser. Twilio makes requests in the format of `application/www-x-form-urlencoded` so you should change:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json())
```

to

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
```

Then you should see the parsed body as part of the `request.body` object.

As an extra note, the `transcribeCallback` is sent asynchronously to the call. So returning TwiML in response to that request won't affect the call at all. You will need to [modify the call in flight, by redirecting it to some new TwiML](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/change-call-state) when you get the result of transcription. An example of [updating a call with Node.js is below](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/change-call-state?code-sample=code-redirect-a-running-call-to-a-new-url&code-language=js&code-sdk-version=3.x):

```
const accountSid = 'your_account_sid';
const authToken = 'your_auth_token';
const client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);

client.calls('CAe1644a7eed5088b159577c5802d8be38')
  .update({
    url: 'http://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml',
    method: 'POST',
  })
  .then((call) => console.log(call.to));
```

Comment: can you please this link " modify the call in flight, by redirecting it to some new TwiML" link of nodejs instead of rest api

Comment: You mean like this example: https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/change-call-state?code-sample=code-redirect-a-running-call-to-a-new-url&code-language=js&code-sdk-version=3.x

Comment: no, i understand how to modifycall using rest api, but i dont want to do it using rest api, i want to do it with 'nodejs twilio sdk'

Comment: give me any link which demonstrate how to modify call using nodejs sdk

Comment: The Node.js SDK uses the REST API to modify calls. It's the only way you can modify a call outside of TwiML. I added the example Node code to the bottom of my answer.

Comment: please also have a look of this question, i'm sure you have answer of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44075338/how-to-play-and-record-voice-at-same-time-in-twilio

Comment: For express 4.16+, following will work: `app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}))`